# How to fix the error when plot the effects of a polr model?

Tags: r, plot, syntax-error

Edit 2: I changed the link (earlier was the wrong link)
Edit 1: My dataframe for this question is like:

| gender | Work less | happy | lifestatisfied | country | Work much |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 7 | 8 | GB | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 8 | 8 | SE | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 7 | 9 | DK | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 6 | 9 | DE | 1 |
| 1 | NA | 7 | 5 | NO | NA |

continued:

| health | education | income | age | marital status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | Na | 61 | NA |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 30 | NA |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 39 | 6 |
| 5 | 7 | 5 | 52 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 | 5 | 17 | 5 |

- country is character (i.e. name of countries) I have 5 countries
- gender is dummy 1 or 2
- age is respondents age like 35, 47 etc.
- income is scaled and is 1 to 10
- educ (education) is 1 to 7
- health is scaled 1 to 5
- work less is dummy i.e. 1 or 0
- work much is dummy, i.e. 1 or 0
- marital status is scaled 1 to 6

I want to make effects plot of my polr model as they do in this example: https://data.library.virginia.edu/visualizing-the-effects-of-proportional-odds-logistic-regression/

I tried and got error which I don't understand why and what I do wrong.
My codes:

```
for.plot <- polr(factor(as.ordered(lifesatisfaction)) ~ country*(gender + age + income + educ + health + work less + work much), data = surveywave5, method = "logistic", Hess = TRUE)

summary(for.plot)

Anova(for.plot)
```

The above codes works and gives the outputs.

The below code does not work and give error:

```
plot(Effect(focal.predictors = c("country","work less"), mod = for.plot, xlevels = list(age = 15:65)), rug = FALSE)
```

this gives the following error:

```
Error in \contrasts<-(\tmp, value = contr.funs[1 + \isOF[nn]]):

contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this error?

structure of my data:

```
str(surveywave5)
tibble [7,936 x 25] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ cntry            : chr+lbl [1:7936] DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE, DE...
   ..@ label       : chr "Country"
   ..@ format.stata: chr "%7s"
   ..@ labels      : Named num [1:27] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:27] "Denmark" "United Kingdom" "Norway" "Germany" ...
 $ gender           : dbl+lbl [1:7936] 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, ...
   ..@ label       : chr "Gender"
   ..@ format.stata: chr "%6.0g"
   ..@ labels      : Named num [1:3] 1 2 9
   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "Male" "Female" "No answer"
 $ marital status   : num [1:7936] NA NA NA 6 6 NA NA NA NA 6 ...
 $ age             : dbl+lbl [1:7936] 61, 30, 39, 52, 17, 50, 31, 49, 50, 39, 45, 42, 62, 27, 52, 19, 17, 20, 62, 34, 18, 59, 17, 46, 37, 59, 49, 21, 27, 40, 47, 52, 21, 46, 38...
   ..@ label       : chr "Age of respondent, calculated"
   ..@ format.stata: chr "%8.0g"
   ..@ labels      : Named num 999
   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "Not available"
 $ income           : num [1:7936] NA 2 4 5 5 10 7 7 6 3 ...
 $ education        : num [1:7936] 3 2 3 7 1 7 3 3 3 5 ...
 $ lifesatisfaction : num [1:7936] 8 8 9 9 9 8 10 9 10 6 ...
 $ happy            : num [1:7936] 9 8 8 8 10 7 10 10 9 6 ...
 $ health           : num [1:7936] 3 4 1 3 4 5 5 4 4 3 ...
 $ work less        : num [1:7936] 0 1 0 0 NA 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ work much        : num [1:7936] 1 0 1 1 NA 0 1 1 0 1 ...
 $ marital status   : num [1:7936] 1 1 1 NA NA 1 1 1 1 NA ...
```

**New try - with as.factor:**

running the regression works fine, and it gives the summary and anova output:

```
for.plot <- polr(as.factor(as.ordered(lifesatisfaction)) ~ as.factor(country)*(gender + age + income + education + health + as.factor(work less) + work much), data = surveywave5, method = "logistic", Hess = TRUE)
```

running this give a new error:

```
plot(Effect(focal.predictors = c("country","work less"), mod = for.plot, xlevels = list(age = 15:65)), rug = FALSE)

Error in Effect(focal.predictors = c("country", "work less"), mod = for.plot, : 
model formula should not contain calls to
factor(), as.factor(), ordered(), as.ordered(), as.numeric(), or as.integer();
see 'Warnings and Limitations' in ?Effect
```

**New try again - making the variables to factor. The structur of the data:**

```
 $ country.new           : Factor w/ 5 levels "DE","DK","GB",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ lifesatisfaction.new  : Ord.factor w/ 11 levels "0"<"1"<"2"<"3"<..: 9 9 10 10 10 9 11 10 11 7 ...        
 $ gender.new          : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ income.new      : Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: NA 2 4 5 5 10 7 7 6 3 ...
 $ eisced          : Factor w/ 7 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 3 2 3 7 1 7 3 3 3 5 ...
 $ health.new        : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 3 4 1 3 4 5 5 4 4 3 ...
 $ work.less.new  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 1 NA 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ work much.new  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 2 NA 1 2 2 1 2 ...
```

The structure of the data in the example is:
[Visualizing the Effects of Proportional-Odds Logistic Regression](https://data.library.virginia.edu/visualizing-the-effects-of-proportional-odds-logistic-regression/?fbclid=IwAR2XMRp8ul8JUog7ExYXbuNVc3dqk55nOJZp_p51PT6kgpAA0R2TCgNsclg)

```
str(WVS)
'data.frame':   5381 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ poverty : Ord.factor w/ 3 levels "Too Little"<"About Right"<..: 1 2 1 3 1 2 3 1 1 1 ...
 $ religion: Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ degree  : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ country : Factor w/ 4 levels "Australia","Norway",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ age     : int  44 40 36 25 39 80 48 32 74 30 ...
 $ gender  : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 ...
```

But it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Please add a `dput` of your data for better reproducibility.

Comment: Hi @NelsonGon, Thanks for you comment! I tried to add an example of the first 5 row of my data. Hope it helps! Just let me know if there is any other information you need.

Comment: Either `country` or `work less` is not a factor. You should turn them into factors. What does the `str` of your data say these classes are?

Comment: Just to let you know, the example of link earlier was wrong. The one I want to make is in here: https://data.library.virginia.edu/visualizing-the-effects-of-proportional-odds-logistic-regression/

Comment: Could you add the `str` of your data to the question? Did you try the fix in the earlier comment?

Comment: @NelsonGon Yes, I added it now, my post is updated

Comment: As you can see "work less" is a numeric, it should be a factor as should `cntry` and maybe marital status and other categorical data. Do `as.factor(column_to_change)`.

Comment: @NelsonGon many thanks for your answer but I got another error using as.factor. My post is updated. The error for the new try is at the bottom. As I understand it says that I cannot use as.factor :/

Comment: Even though I make a new variable with as factor with country and work less, like this: `surveywave5$country.new = as.factor(surveywave5$country)` does not work using them in the polr regression. It gives the same error as the first time `Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels`

Comment: @NelsonGon I looked at the `str` data they use in the example and maked my data as theirs.. but it still doesn't work.. I don't know what I do wrong :/ My post is updated with this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm currently not on PC. Will try to check it out as soon as possible if someone else does not.

Comment: @NelsonGon no problem, I totally understand! But I solved my problem. My question is updated if you want to have a look at it, you can see it in the last part bottom with header "New try - works now". Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: If you solved your own problem, the best thing to do (encouraged!) is to post the solution as an **answer to your own question** (which you can then accept), not to edit your question to include the answer ...

Comment: @BenBolker I did it now, thanks for you comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, now I figured out what was wrong. I need to recode the variables using as.factor to change them in the dataframe instead of using the as.factor inside the polr regression.
So, I code it as:

```
surveywave5$country = as.factor(surveywave5$country)
surveywave5$lifesatisfied = as.factor(as.ordered((surveywave5$lifesatisfied)))
surveywave5$gender = as.factor(surveywave5$gender)
surveywave5$age = as.integer(surveywave5$age)
surveywave5$income = as.factor(surveywave5$income)
surveywave5$work less = as.factor(surveywave5$work less)
```

and then running the regression with:

```
for.plot <- polr(lifesatisfaction ~ country*(gender + age + income + health + work less), data = surveywave5, method = "logistic", Hess = TRUE)

plot(Effect(focal.predictors = c("country","age","gender"), mod = for.plot, xlevels = list(age = 15:65), latent = TRUE), rug = FALSE)
```

Gives me a plot very much similar to this:
[country * age * gender effect plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwja3.png)

Comment: For easier recoding, I think you should use `dplyr`'s `mutate` as it is more readable. You can do this in one line with `mutate(across..)` and converting all target columns to factor at once.

Comment: @NelsonGon Thanks for your tip/advise. I will have a look at it and learn how it is used and use it if I can.